# DataFrame column addition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, that looks like the following: (with only one column)

**`col1 
 0
 0
 11
 34
 5
 0
 72`**

But I want to add one column, col2. If the element in col1 is non zero, the corresponding element in col2 will be the string "play". But if it is zero, it will be either zero or just NA. Like the following.

**`col1     col2
 0        NA
 0        NA
 11      Play
 34      Play
 5       Play
 0        NA
 72      Play`**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `col2` like this:

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1']!=0, 'Play', 'NA')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: 'Play' if x !=0 else 'NA')
```

Comment: Although technically correct we should avoid posting answers that use `apply` where a vectorised solution exists as this confuses users